# Schematic design for CJMCU Beetle?

Tags: avr, atmega32u4

I have this bare ATMEGA32U4 breakout:

[image]

There are no components on the backside, and I need to redesign this for my own purposes.

I'm looking for the schematic design of this. Although I can reverse engineer this, but if someone has this schematics, it would save me quite some time.

What I found online seems correct:

[image]

However I don't know:

- X1 XTAL's frequency
- Z1 and Z2 Zeners' voltage (or 22 means 2V2?)

Comment: I mean, whatever you'll use this for, you would need to select a crystal frequencya yourself. So what's the point in copying this?

Comment: As @MarcusMüller alludes to, the crystal is a variable frequency. Check out pages 29/30 in the datasheet for more info: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-7766-8-bit-avr-atmega16u4-32u4_datasheet.pdf

Comment: considering Z1 and Z2 don't use diode and especially Zener symbols, my guess is that this schematic is already reverse-engineered / a translation to a more standard symbology of a worse schematic, by the way, but not done by someone who really knows what they're doing. I mean, diodes have polarity! Also, in "GND" symbols going up is not something you're usually taught at school/university (and IMHO for good reason); nor is using a capital "U" when you mean to say "micro". I'd say you'd not be badly advised to reverse-engineer the circuit yourself, or even better:

Comment: Come on, design this circuit yourself. Your friendly microcontroller vendor has reference circuits that you can just copy for free and which are better; they'd include appropriate loading capacitors for your crystal, maybe one or two ceramic 10 nF to 100 nF caps closer to the different VCC pins,and generally be more stable than this design, if I even may call this *design* – it's essentially itself just a copy of a reference circuit, hand tuned to cost as little as possible by relying on parasitics and "90% of the time, it works all the time". It's not *good work* you're planning to copy here.

Comment: it was designed by DFROBOT. they have a good web site

Comment: @Juraj: On DFRobot I didn't find schematics, or you are referring them for the values of the XTAL etc?

Comment: Folks, I know that I can check the datasheet for the XTAL frequencies. I wished to know which XTAL is this board using, as my project is working perfectly on this board, but I need to redesign due to size constraints.

Comment: But your software needs to either know the frequency, or didn't use the crystal oscillator... So, just look inside your software and check which crystal oscillator frequency it assumes, I guess?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: true. Currently the software is created with Arduino Studio (which I don't like, as it masks a lot of details), and I don't know which XTAL setting it uses if I select "Arduino Leonardo".

Comment: @winny: why would it be the *best* bet? I mean what would be the point of loading (pulling down) the D+ and D- lines?

Comment: @Daniel does the Arduino Leonardo not have a schematic that tells you that?

Comment: @winny well, if it's a resistor in a place where a "22"-labeled resistor would completely break all functionality, then something about the labeling is false.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Oh wait, there are 22 ohm in series too. Then it's the green thingamajigs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit: One of these showed up in my lab, apparently identical to yours.  I measured the frequency of the resonator at 16 MHz.  The resonator appears to be similar to this [Murata](https://www.murata.com/products/productdata/8801162231838/SPEC-CSTNE16M0V530000R0.pdf) device, which matches the case size and frequency marking of A for 16 MHz.  (Mine is marked AE, in contrast to your AX, consistent with E and X being date codes.)*

My suggestion would be to copy those portions of the circuit from an actual [Arduino Leonardo](https://docs.arduino.cc/static/05f737fc664415f0e33201f8c2078672/schematics.pdf), which uses the same CPU, the ATMega32U4.

The Leonardo uses a specialist ESD protector, a 5 V varistor (Bourns [CG0603MLC-05E](https://www.bourns.com/docs/product-datasheets/cga-mlc.pdf)) not a diode. Some other USB protection circuits use 3.6 V Zener diodes, but the ESD protector is probably better.

[image]
Redrawn from Leonardo diagram

For the clock, the Leonardo has a 16 MHz crystal (with 22 pF capacitors).  As others have noted, you have a choice about the frequency. Common other values are 8 MHz or use the internal clock sources. You really should read the clock source portions of the 32U4 datasheet, as there are a lot of ways of doing it. If you're making your own with a crystal, don't omit the capacitors. As noted in comments, you can also use a ceramic resonator, as in your original CJMCU circuit, which doesn't need the capacitors, but which also shouldn't have the resistor.

[image]
From Leonardo diagram

Comment: The provided schematic uses a 3-pin ceramic resonator with built-in loading caps. There's nothing wrong with that, as long as accurate enough component is used for whatever purpose required. The 1 megaohm resistor however does not belong there. There is no need to copy mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The reverse-engineered schematics are likely correct.

The design is just not worth copying. It has mistakes and weird stuff you really don't want to copy. You really want to do it properly and avoid mistakes.

Use the manufacturer schematic examples in the AVR datasheet rather than copy mistakes of existing design.

For the XTAL frequency, use what data sheet suggests. It is possible that multiple different values are OK, at least USB may require a specific clock. Some bad designs use too high clock. The correct clock will be in the data sheet. This schematic has a resistor between the crystal terminals. There should be no requirement for that resistor. But also thia design does not use a crystal, but a ceramic resonator with built-in loading capacitors. It may or may not be accurate enough for USB communications. A crystal will be better than ceramic resonator. Please refer to datasheet how to connect it.

For the zeners, as this MCU has a real USB interface, they should not be zeners, there should be no need for zeners at all. They might simply be ESD protection diodes.